# Why kotlin-stdlib-1.3.31.jar does not have IntArray.class, MutableList.class even though they are part of stdlib?

Tags: kotlin

I want to figure out what are the system classes that are included in kotlin stdlib. But classes like IntArray, MutableList are not part of kotlin-stdlib.jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are [mapped types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types), which are not actual JVM classes but are mapped to other types. For instance, `IntArray` is mapped to the JVM array type `int[]`, and `MutableList` is mapped to `java.util.List`.